# Proper way to add custom assets to Keras model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to include arbitrary assets to my `saved_model` (for example, a text file/json mapping label indices to their proper names). Historically, I just manually save the assets to `{saved_model_path}/assets/custom_asset.txt`.

Today I came across [tf.saved_model.Asset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/Asset) which seems like a clean way to do this:

```
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint()
checkpoint.my_filename = tf.saved_model.Asset('some_file.txt')

# Normal model saving stuff
model.save(saved_model_path)

# Save tf.saved_model.Asset
tf.saved_model.save(checkpoint, saved_model_path)
```

The above seems to save the model fine, plus the custom asset shows up in the `{saved_model}/assets` directory as expected. Clearly I'm doing something wrong:

- Using `saved_model_cli` to inspect the model shows different signatures and such compared to doing the same thing, but not saving the custom trackable object.
- Loading the model fails:

---

```
# Attempting to load the model in a separate process
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(path)

>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rsilveira/dev/ddm-ml-classifieds-recommender/tf_model_exporter.py", line 80, in <module>
    load(_saved_model_path)
  File "/Users/rsilveira/dev/ddm-ml-classifieds-recommender/tf_model_exporter.py", line 67, in load
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(path)
  File "/Users/rsilveira/dev/ddm-ml-classifieds-recommender/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/rsilveira/dev/ddm-ml-classifieds-recommender/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/saving/saved_model/load.py", line 466, in _revive_from_config
    obj, self._proto.nodes[node_id], node_id)
IndexError: list index (62) out of range
```

## Question

Is there a "native" Tensorflow-y way to save custom assets (not attached to the model)?

## Reproducible code

```
# Create some dummy model
def build_model():
    i = Input(shape=(5,))
    fc = Dense(5, activation='relu')(i)
    softmax = Dense(5, activation='softmax', name='Softmax')(fc)

    return Model(inputs=i, outputs=softmax)

# Some dummy model
model = build_model()
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.003)

model.compile(optimizer=opt,
    metrics=[SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
    loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False))

# Dummy data
_ds = Dataset.from_tensor_slices((np.random.rand(10, 5), np.random.randint(0, 5, 10)))

model.fit(_ds.batch(32), epochs=3)

# Save the model
model.save(saved_model_path)

some_file = 'some_file.txt'
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint()
checkpoint.my_filename = tf.saved_model.Asset(some_file)

tf.saved_model.save(checkpoint, saved_model_path)

# Loading the model - in a different process
model = tf.keras.models.load_model(saved_model_path)
```

Comment: Will probably work if you load the model with `model = tf.saved_model.load(saved_model_path)`

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. It does load, and I do see my custom asset. However, I can't call it (trying to follow along https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/load): `TypeError: '_UserObject' object is not callable`. Looks clear that using `tf.train.Checkpoint` is not what I want, since I'd still like to interact with the original Keras object.